# Android: Highlight Currently Selected option in listview programmatically

Tags: android, listview

I have a list in which I show a few options to the user. I also have two buttons for next and previous.  On next new options are bound from the database.

**Issue:**

On press of the previous button I want to show the previously selected state. Sadly I am unable to highlight the selected row.

```
 listviewoptions = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstviewoptionAptitude);
            
    listviewoptions.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position ,
                long arg3) {
            
             if (previouslySelectedItem != null)
                {
                    previouslySelectedItem.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                            //getResources().getColor(R.color.pressed_color));
                }

             String Selectedcolor = "#fdc500";
             arg1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(Selectedcolor));
                       // getResources().getColor(R.color.default_color));

                previouslySelectedItem = arg1;
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"programitically Clicked", Toast. LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             response = position+1;

        }
    });
```

**Function GetPrevious Selected Option**

```
public void getoptionSelected(Integer StudentIDResponse , String QuestionIDResponse)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = null;
    String selectQuestion = "Select * from TableResponse where StudentID = "+StudentIDResponse+" AND QuestionID ="+QuestionIDResponse;
    c = db.rawQuery(selectQuestion, null);
    if(  c.getCount() >0) {
     if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                
             strOptionResponseID = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("QuestOptionID"));  
                
            } while (c.moveToNext());        
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //No response Found
    }
 }
```

**What I am trying on previous Button**

```
  public void PrevQuestion()
   {
       getoptionSelected(StudentID,QuestionID);
       
       if (strOptionResponseID !=null)
       {
          **1st Method I tried** 
           
           response = Integer.parseInt(strOptionResponseID);
           listviewoptions.performItemClick(
                   listviewoptions.getAdapter().getView(response, null, null),
                   response,
                    listviewoptions.getAdapter().getItemId(response));
           
          **2nd Method I tried**

           listviewoptions.performItemClick(listviewoptions.getAdapter().getView(3, null, null), 3, listviewoptions.getItemIdAtPosition(3));
           listviewoptions.setSelection(response);
           listviewoptions.getSelectedView().setSelected(true);
       }
```

**Update**

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

    public ListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
    }

    public ListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Item> items) {
        super(context, resource, items);
    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        if (position == 1)
        {
             String Selectedcolor = "#fdc500";
            // arg1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(Selectedcolor));
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(Selectedcolor));
        }
        else
        {
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        }
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want highlight the selected row follow the steps that I have mentioned in the below link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31805381/list-item-selector-does-not-show-rounded-corner-on-press?noredirect=1#comment51537586_31805381

Comment: you need to set the background for row item with selector file and follow the steps that I have mentioned in previous comment and let me know.

Comment: I am able to highlight on touch.. I wan to achieve it programitically

Comment: Maintain a boolean variable for selected item and find the layout or view in adapter based on that boolean value you  can change the view background in getview() method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1**

yourlistview.setItemChecked(iposition, true);
//here iposition is an int to the selected position

**Step 2**

```
List<String> options = db.getAllOptions(QuestionID);

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                   R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, R.id.text1, options);

            listviewoptions.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 2):

Two ways you can show the selection.

1] set choicemode as "SingleChoice"to listView and use a custom "Checkable" View [find here](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/widget/Checkable.html.) .

2] Override getView() and change the background based on some member variable.

```
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

            if (this_is_the_selected_item)
            {
                view.setBackgroundColor(selectedcolor);
            }
            else
            {
                view.setBackgroundColor(Normal_color);
            }
            return view;
        }
```

Comment: The method getView(int, View, ViewGroup) is undefined for the type Activity

Comment: @tusharnarang get View method is for the list adapter . Override the adapter  check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166497/custom-adapter-for-list-view

Comment: pls see the updated section in my question... It doesnt work either